# Output in XHTML or HTML 5 for plugins?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, html, html5

I'm currently writing a plugin that displays some images - possibly with captions. So, I was wondering whether to use XHTML (`<div>`s and `<span>`s) or HTML 5 (`<figure>` and `<figurecaption>`) for output.

I image that the answer to this question depends somewhat on the theme being used. Is there a way to figure out which output format the user's theme is using? Or what's the best approach here? What's Wordpress doing to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WordPress will not help you here. In back-end use conservative XHTML 5: `<br />`, but not `<figure>` (see [WP coding standards](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards#HTML)).

In front-end … it is hard to determine the Doctype and the usage of [polyfills](http://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill/), so stay with regular HTML as long as possible or load the necessary polyfills from your plugin.